# number border effect

Tags: css

i want to bring the following effect on one of my projects as in yahoo search.i tried a lot but couldnot make it.please somebody help me.![alt text][1]

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b253a30c3b.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Make your links block-level and use a border like this:

```
a{
  display:block
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Should remove "display:block".

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

> <style>
>
> a {padding:3px; border:1px #000000 solid;}
>
> </style>